# Django: иная структура проекта или каким образом подключить приложение?

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго времени суток!
Имеется подобная структура проекта:

```
project_dir
- startproject_dir
  - base
    - всё, что касается приложения "base"
  - всё, что касается startproject_dir (setting, urls, wsgi)
```

Подключаю приложение в settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

Однако если переместить приложение base в project_dir (то есть стандартное расположение приложений), то ошибка пропадает.

Как же тут быть?

Comment: Django версии 2.1

Comment: startproject_dir.base.apps.BaseConfig (естественно, не забудьте позаботиться о том, чтобы startproject_dir был python-модулем)

Comment: Такое решение тоже пробовал:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'base'. Check that 'picra.base.apps.BaseConfig.name' is correct.
В каждой папке я создал __init__.py перед этим, конечно же

Comment: Пробовали сделать то, что предлагает сделать текст этой ошибки?